# Order of foreign keys/cascades processing in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, constraint, concurrency

I have a parent table and 2 (or more) children tables with foreign key defined with some cascade option. So when an entry from a parent table is being deleted, SQL Server will check 2 (or more) children tables to perform relevant cascade action. The question is - is there a specific order in which SQL Server will process those cascade actions - and, correspondingly, is there an order in which locks are taken on those children rows/pages/tables?

That seems quite relevant for deadlock investigations, however I couldn't find info in BOL or here.

Comment: AFAIR this ordering is not specified.

Comment: Even if you could determine a specific order, it is not defined or documented, and could change at any time. Take control, stop using cascade, and handle the deletes to the child tables yourself, e.g. in an instead of trigger.

Comment: Or implement the deletion logic as its own unit of work "package" (stored procedure, DAL, etc) where it deletes from the bottom up.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Thanks for your input, much appreciated! That's what we did - threw the cascade out and rewrote the deletion logic. It just seems there's very little info on the fact that multiple cascades defined on a single parent table can cause hard-to-fix deadlocks, so I thought this question would help others.

Comment: You can also mix DELETE CASCADE and RESTRICT. I use it very frequently in my DB design especially when small tables are used to design an independant component. For instance a physical person break down into 4 or more parts : person, phone, email, address and adress details in CASCADE mode. But an order table, affairing to a person, will be in the RESTRICT mode.

Comment: @SQLpro I don't believe SQL Server has ever implemented `RESTRICT`.

Comment: Due to the absence of deferred constraint in SQL Server RESTRICT and NO ACTION has the same behaviour.... But you are right !